# PHP - preg_replace and str_replace only replace only once inside foreach

Tags: replace, preg-replace, str-replace, glob

I have a foreach that uses a Glob function in order to get some .htm files and finally put that content in one echo.

I Tried to replace one specific phrase located in all this .htm files with some data that I extract from the each .htm filename.

So,

`$juzgado_radicado` generates a number like ---> `004`

`$year_radicado` generates a number like ---> `2015`

`$radicado_radicado` generates a number like ---> `00911`

That numbers are changing depending of `foreach` iteration getting a new file name.

But at the end I use `preg_replace` or `str_replace` in order to change a phrase inside the each .htm document but instead replacing the numbers in each iteration I only get the same result in all replaces. So I get something like "00911" in all .htm files and it have to be something like "00911" and "00577" por example.

I don't know why `preg_replace` and `str_replace` have this behaviour inside the `foreach` loop.

```php
$directory2 = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tecnojuridica/finalizado/";
$array_filename = glob($directory2 . "*.htm");
$string = '';

foreach($array_filename as $filename)
    {
    $xml_file = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
    preg_match('/[0-9]{23}/', $filename, $match);
    $radicado = $match[0];

    // 002

    $juzgado_radicado = substr($radicado, -14, 3);

    // 2015

    $year_radicado = substr($radicado, -11, 4);

    // 00958

    $radicado_radicado = substr($filename, -7, 5);

    // Dom Object

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $dom->xmlStandalone = true;
    $dom->loadHTML($xml_file);
    $content_node = $dom->getElementById("divrandom");
    $mega = $dom->saveXML($content_node);

    $string2 = preg_replace('/Datos del Proceso/', ' <font size="30"> <span style="background-color: #73A6FF; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 3px 10px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;">' . $juzgado_radicado . '</span> <span style="background-color: #73A6FF; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 3px 10px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;">' . $year_radicado . '</span> <span style="background-color: #73A6FF; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 3px 10px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;">' . $radicado_radicado . ' </span> </font>', $mega);
    $string.= $mega . ',';
    }

echo utf8_decode($string2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the Answer: You have to replace at star of the foreach loop not with Php `Dom Document` Objects.

If you tried to make replacement into Dom Objects it's possible that fails because `str_replace` of `preg_replace` can't make all iterations with different replace data.